# Are there any fonts with Asian coverage that can be used freely on web-pages?

Tags: fonts, web

I have searched through the site but didn't find anything related to my question so I'm asking; I also hope this is the right place to ask.

I've tried to look around but there seems to be lack of free fonts that support Asian scripts and that can be used freely on the internet.

Are there (preferably official) sites that provide such fonts for free? All of those I found support only Latin/Cyrillic/Greek but not Asian like Chinese/Japanese/Korean scripts.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by web-safe. Perhaps this may help? http://unifont.org/fontguide/ - Open-sourced Unicode font faces.

Comment: @JohnChadwick Fonts that are not proprietary and that can be therefore used freely, without infringing any copyright. :) Thanks, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: I have edited the Question to remove "Web-Safe" as it has been much used elsewhere to mean something different. If you disagree with my changes, please undo them.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick No problem, the meaning seems the same to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Arial Unicode MS can be used on Windows Platforms, where it is <strike>fairly ubiquitous</strike> *often found*, and supports Asian languages.

Most current browsers will seek out glyphs in all available fonts on the client platform regardless of the font specified in the CSS (or in the HTML if you are a contrarian).

All Fonts have copyrights *(somewhere, probably)*, it's just that some of them have licences that allow free redistribution  and some have licences that don't. Arial Unicode MS falls somewhere in the middle.

Comment: "Arial Unicode MS" is part of office, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS ...

Comment: AFAIK, in US law, works can be placed in the public domain, which forfeits all copyrights.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Presumably a work can be PD in the US and still have copyrights in those parts of the rebel alliance that have not yet been crushed?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I think so. I know that copyright works very differently in some countries. There is no way to place a work into the public domain in Germany, it's not even possible to transfer copyright (the German version of these rights is authorship rights, Urheberrecht) to another party completely. I don't think a work's foreign voluntary public domain status is recognized either.

Comment: @akira: that article says "normally distributed with" not "part of". Whether this distinction is important is moot. It is also distributed with OSX and has previously been made available in a variety of ways. I guess the important point is that it may not be as ubiquitous as I said.